# /bin/sh: eval: line 125: /home/node/artillery/bin/artillery: not found when running the Artillery's sample .gitlab-ci.yml on CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, artillery, gitlab-ci.yml

I am a beginner and I want to try to integrate Artillery on Gitlab CI/CD, so I looked for Artillery's documentation and found the steps on how to do it. I followed the instructions and use this sample configuration found in the documentation:

```
artillery:
  image:
    name: artilleryio/artillery:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  script: |
    mkdir reports
    /home/node/artillery/bin/artillery run --output reports/report.json tests/performance/socket-io.yml
    /home/node/artillery/bin/artillery report --output reports/report reports/report.json
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - reports
```

source: https://www.artillery.io/docs/guides/integration-guides/gitlab-ci-cd

I committed the file and the pipeline starts to run, but after awhile it failed and the error was:

**Error: /bin/sh: eval: line 125: /home/node/artillery/bin/artillery: not found**

Here's the full log:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.3.0~beta.42.gdb7789ca (db7789ca)
  on blue-4.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default J2nyww-s
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
Using Docker executor with image artilleryio/artillery:latest ...
Pulling docker image artilleryio/artillery:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:27f94fdd50befb4a245e7352f51747330c3b05922133681869c822460f9065a2 for artilleryio/artillery:latest with digest artilleryio/artillery@sha256:1637c7dd4ed15020612faef63f7e0be6200634c7336ad1bf5b60bab4b5f797b0 ...
Preparing environment
00:02
Running on runner-j2nyww-s-project-38396163-concurrent-0 via runner-j2nyww-s-shared-1660008636-37f7076a...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/trial304/artillery-load-test/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 51807ad5 as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:27f94fdd50befb4a245e7352f51747330c3b05922133681869c822460f9065a2 for artilleryio/artillery:latest with digest artilleryio/artillery@sha256:1637c7dd4ed15020612faef63f7e0be6200634c7336ad1bf5b60bab4b5f797b0 ...
$ mkdir reports # collapsed multi-line command
/bin/sh: eval: line 125: /home/node/artillery/bin/artillery: not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

I've been looking for an answer anywhere, but I can't find any solution to fix the pipeline error.
Your inputs are very welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run this, you can get a shell so that you can view the contents of directories:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh artilleryio/artillery:latest
```

Looking at the contents of that directory, I believe what you are looking for is the `run` command:

```
/home/node/artillery/bin/run
```

You can view available command by running `run -h`. So I believe you are wanting this:

```
/home/node/artillery/bin/run run --output reports/report.json tests/performance/socket-io.yml
/home/node/artillery/bin/run report --output reports/report reports/report.json
```

Comment: Hi @ericfossas , it worked finally! So artillery is replaced by run. Thank you so much I can finally move on :D

Comment: For documentation, the issue was solved by changing this `</home/node/artillery/bin/artillery` to `/home/node/artillery/bin/run` Then it will become:  <br/> ` /home/node/artillery/bin/run run --output reports/report.json tests/performance/socket-io.yml` <br/> `/home/node/artillery/bin/run report --output reports/report reports/report.json`